# dataTables columnDefs changes on reload

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a call to `dataTables()` in a function as I use it for several events and is called initially from `$(document).ready()`.  It works as expected on the initial call.  There is an event listener that fires when either of two select boxes (`#jobtype`,`#jobstatus`) with a class of `.filter` is changed.  This event listener calls the `loadtable()` function again.  The correct data is returned based on the select boxes, but the column widths are all off.  My entire `<script>` tag is below.

It is not an issue with the data being wider on the second call either.

Where am I missing why the column width properties are getting changed?

```
<script>

    var table;

    function loadtable() {
        var jobtype = $('#jobtype').val();
        var status = $('#jobstatus').val();

        if (table) {
            table.destroy();
        };

        table = $('#events').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'pageLength': 25,
            'lengthMenu': [[10, 15, 20, 25, 50], [10, 15, 20, 25, 50]],
            'ajax': {
                'url': 'LoadEvents/' + jobtype + '/' + status,
                'type': 'POST',
                'dataType': 'json'
            },
            'columns': [
                { 'data': 'Id', 'name': 'Id' }, // 0
                { 'data': 'JobNumber', 'name': 'JobNumber' }, // 1
                { 'data': 'JobType', 'name': 'JobType' }, // 2
                { 'data': 'Status', 'name': 'Status' }, // 3
                { 'data': 'JobDateTime', 'name': 'JobDateTime' }, // 4
                { 'data': 'LogText', 'name': 'LogText' }, // 5
                { 'data': 'FullLog', 'name': 'FullLog' }, // 6
                { 'data': 'XML', 'name': 'XML' }, // 7
                { 'data': 'FullXML', 'name': 'FullXML' } // 8
            ],
            'columnDefs': [
                { 'visible': false, 'targets': [0, 6, 8] },
                { 'sortable': false, 'targets': [0] },
                { 'width': '25px', 'targets': [1] },
                { 'width': '150px', 'targets': [2] },
                { 'width': '125px', 'targets': [4] },
                { 'width': '50px', 'targets': [3] },
                {
                    'render': function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<span class="expand" data-type="log" id="' + row.Id + '">' + data + '<span style="display: none">' + row.FullLog + '</span></span>';
                    },
                    'targets': 5
                },
                {
                    'render': function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<span class="expand" data-type="xml" id="' + row.Id + '">' + data + '<span style="display: none">' + row.FullXML + '</span></span>';
                    },
                    'targets': 7
                }
            ],
            'order': [
                [4, 'desc']
            ]
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadtable();
    });

    $(document).on('change',
        '.filter',
        function() {
            loadtable();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try if `if (table) { $('#events').empty(); table.destroy(); }` will work

Comment: @emineminems - Same issue

Comment: Try adding `table.columns.adjust().draw();` once the table is initialized - [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust())

Comment: @Shashank - nope. No joy  I just can't get why two calls to the same function results in different markup.

Comment: Can you post a working snippet on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) real quick with some dummy data?

Comment: `'width': '25px'` will never, ever work satisfactory, `width` only target a relative width, a percentage, and you must turn `autoWidth` off. The only real solution to control the column widths accurately is to use targeted CSS, or `className` pointing to a CSS class as in the duplicate link.. Sry for linking to my own answer.